# Display Crosshairs in XTK 2D View

Tags: xtk

Is there a way to display the colored x,y,z crosshairs that are visible in the 3D volume view in 2D slices (like in lesson 13)?

Thanks!

Nolan

Answer (score 0):

the crosshairs are just borders around the slices. What do you have in mind to display them in 2D?

Comment: Since I can't click on the image to identify voxel coordinates, I was thinking about using the the "boarders around the slices" as a way of displaying cross hairs to pinpoint a voxel. This way a user could use the UI controls to scroll through the indexX, indexY, and indexZ controls and see where they intersect in the 2D slices. Is there a way to display these boarders in 2D?